Get the list of nested folders in directory and filter by name in batch script
I am trying to write a batch function where i need exclude some folders while searching in directory
Main Folder
  --ProjA Folder
     --A Folder
       --A.csproj
      --Aa Folder
        -Aa.csproj
     -- B Folder
      --B.csproj
     -- C Folder
       --c.csproj

When i tried with this function,its giving me project file names in all nested subfolders.
Set MainDir="C:\users\Main"
 cd %MainDir%
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b *.csproj') do if exist %%x (

    echo %%~dpx
)

But I need to exclude B folder related B.csproj files. Please let me know how can we apply filter for this particular subfolder

Your question needs clarification. First your title says, "Get the list of nested folders". Then you say that you "need exclude some folders". Next you show a tree representation where we cannot determine what's a file and what may be a directory. You include a For loop which performs a Dir command but does not isolate files from directories, and state that it lists "project file names". However using %%~dpx means it cannot! You state that you "need to exclude B folder related B.csproj files", even though it defintely does not attempt that, or need to, because no files are output anyhow.

A better representation of the folder structure and files in it would be to use the tree command.

Additionally, as you are specifically wanting to filter output, it would certainly be considerably better to use the real directory names, rather than those clearly fake and non-representative ones. My best guess, from what you submitted, is that you really want to perform a command against every .csproj file in the 'Main' directory tree, except for children, (and maybe grandchildren etc.), under a named directory. Is that what you were supposed to be telling us is the actual task?

[Theoretical only]
Set "MainDir=C:\users\Main"
cd %MainDir%
for /f "delims=" %%e in ('dir /s /b *.csproj^|find /i /v "\ProjA Folder\B Folder\"') do if exist "%%e" (

    echo %%~dpe
)

Notes:
Use set "var=value" for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign " or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax set var="value" is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.
Changed metavariable from %%x to %%e since x is also a metavariable modifier (see for /? from the prompt) which can lead to hard-to-spot problems.
Quoted metavariable in if exist so that filenames including spaces should be handled correctly.
Use ^| (escaped pipe) to filter output of dir using find to report filenames which do not (/v) contain the case-insensitive (/i) string "\ProjA Folder\B Folder\".
Your code should report the drive and path for each file encountered that matches the filemask *.csproj
